# jQuery Error - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are many questions where this jQuery Error was the problem. But how you may see, this error isn't very helpful at all for solving the problem. I work with jQuery 1.10.2 and have a plugin at version 1.3 called jRumble included.

Now the error comes with this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.landing-bar').jrumble({
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        rotation: 0
    });

    var rumbleStart = function() {
        jQuery('.landing-bar').trigger('startRumble');
        setTimeout(rumbleStop, 200);
    };

    var rumbleStop = function() {
        jQuery('.landing-bar').trigger('stopRumble');
        setTimeout(rumbleStart, 785);
    };

    rumbleStart();
    animateScroll();
}); 

function animateScroll() {
    jQuery('.landing-bar').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, {
        duration: 30000,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete:function() { 
            jQuery(this).css("width","0%");
        }
    });
    animateScroll();
}
```

What is wrong with my code? I think it could be, that a syntax is wrong for jQuery 1.10..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you have an infinite recursion happening in  `animateScroll`.... why are you calling `animateScroll` inside `animateScroll`

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?  What method is being called when the error is thrown?

Comment: use `setTimeout(animateScroll,30000)` instead of directly calling animateScroll, or better yet call `animateScroll()` within the animate done callback

Comment: @ArunPJohny that has to be like that. It is a Loadingbar which should start going to 100% in width when it reached the 100%.. am I not allowed to do it like that?

Comment: @ArunPJohny to be able to start the whole "growing to 100%" process again and again

Comment: recall function inside complete callback

Comment: Wny don't you use `setInterval` instead of self-calling `setTimeout`?

Comment: recalling it inside the "complete" callback worked for me. Thanks @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `animateScoll()` in your `complete` callback. You don't want it to be called over and over again like that.

```
function animateScroll() {
    jQuery('.landing-bar').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, {
        duration: 30000,
        easing: 'linear',
        complete:function() { 
            jQuery(this).css("width","0%");
            animateScroll();
        }
    });

}
```

EXPLANATION:

the jQuery callback `complete` is called when your animating has finished. What you are essentially doing is calling the animate function over and over again (within milliseconds of the previous call) and filling the interpreter stack with a recursive function that never ends.

Stack would look like:

```
animateScroll()
animateScroll()
animateScroll()
animateScroll()
animateScroll()
...
```

What you need is:

```
animateScroll()
animateScroll()
complete:function()
animateScroll()
complete:function()
animateScroll()
complete:function()
animateScroll()
...
```

so that each step completes before a new one is called.